# Suppose $b \neq 0$, then $a/b > 0$ iff either ($a > 0$ and $b > 0$) or ($a < 0$ and $b < 0$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, real-numbers

> Suppose $b \neq 0$, then $a/b > 0$ iff either ($a > 0$ and $b > 0$) or ($a < 0$ and $b < 0$)

Since it's an *iff*, I know I must prove both implications. I tried to prove,

*($a > 0$ and $b > 0$) or ($a < 0$ and $b < 0$)*  $\implies $ $ab > 0$

and then tried to prove that

$a/b > 0 \implies ab > 0$

I just can't seem to get past this point (if it's even the right step).

Comment: *Hint*: $x^2>0$ for all real $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a/b > 0$. 
Let $m = a/b$. 
Then $m > 0$. 
If $b > 0$, then by multiplying both sides of the inequality by $b$, we get $b \cdot m > 0$. But $b \cdot m = b \cdot a/b = a$. Then $a > 0$. 
On the other hand, if $b < 0$, then multiplying both sides of the inequality by $b$, we get $b \cdot m < 0$. Then $a < 0$. 
Hence if $a/b > 0$, then $a,b > 0$ or $a,b < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $b$ and $1/b$ have the same sign.
Since the product is positive iff both factors are positive or both are negative  the same is true the quotient.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with formalization of the problem:
$$\forall a\forall b((b\neq0\rightarrow(a/b>0))\leftrightarrow((a>0\land b>0)\lor(a<0\land b<0)))$$
When proving **only if** part of the given formula you can use the *multiplicative inverse* property of real numbers. For the case when $(a> 0\land b > 0)$:
\begin{array}{}
 a>0\\ 
 a*1>0\\
 b*1/b = 1\\
 a * (b * 1/b) >0\\
 (a/b) * b > 0\\
 b > 0\\
 a/b > 0\\
\end{array}